# Best way to generate large text file using TPL or Async

Tags: c#, io, task-parallel-library

I have a table with around 500K records.
I need to export the data into a text file.

What is the best way to do that? Does .NET Task Parallel or Async help?
I am thinking to use Parallel to create multiple files, then combine together.

Is that good approach? Very appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: You still have I/O to deal with when writing all the files. I think this is one of those areas where concurrency won't help you.

Comment: "best" is subjective. What do you count as "best"? Just doing a simple loop writing each record would be simple, and usually just about as quick as any other method. So, is there any reason you can't do that?

Comment: Thanks, Pscs. The "best" here, I actually mean "perform best". Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to write this to a file and the data is in memory, parallelizing will not matter much, as the bottleneck will be the disk. Simply write to the disk sequentially using a `StreamWriter`.

If you need to obtain or calculate the data, then you could try parallelizing the calculation.

In any case, disk writing performance will not be improved by parallelization. In fact, if you try to parallelize it, you might get worse performance.

Comment: So if the resulting output is not incredibly large (say, <1GB), it would make sense to write to `MemoryStream`, and then dump it on the disk.

Comment: +1 the performance of concurrency here might in fact be worse. Writing to multiple files, then reading multiple files, then writing one large file, sounds like a bad deal.

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the Streamwriter! (with the using statement if possible)

Comment: Thank you, Joker_vD! How about BufferedStream, or use MemoryMapped file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class  which exposes a Stream around a file, supporting both synchronous and asynchronous read and write operations.